# connection failed : Bad Url (null) error while sending POST data from Xcode to classic ASP page.

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsurl

In my iphone project, I need to pass member Id and pwd to a web server. I have tried my code with Synchronous as well as asynchronous request but I always get error : connection failed: Bad URL (null). can any one please help me to find what's wrong with the code?

My code:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"memberId=%@&pwd=%@",txtUName.text,txtPwd.text];
 NSLog(@"%@",post);    
NSURL *url = [NSURL
              URLWithString:@"http://testweb.talkfusion.com/videocenter/xlogin.asp%@"];    
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                      allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

//set up the request to the website
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The %@ at the end in your url is wrong. POST-data are not part of the url.